# media search for iPad

Tags: css

I am trying to get the @media search to work but with not success. I am using the following code but the only image I can displayed is the headernew.jpg never the headerold.jpg so it seams that none of the media queries are working. I have tested on a 27in iMac and a iPad but both display the same background image. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks Roger

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left:-50%;
width: 1344px;
height: 150px;
background-image: url('../img/headernew.jpg');
/* Only affects 1600px width */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 1600px){ background-image: url('../img/headerold.jpg');}
    /* Only affects 1200px width */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px){ background-image: url('../img/headerold.jpg');}
    /* Only affects 900px width */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 900px){ background-image: url('../img/headerold.jpg');}
    /* Only affects 600px width */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px){ background-image: url('../img/headerold.jpg');}
    /* Only affects 400px width */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 400px){ background-image: url('../img/headerold.jpg');}
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
```

Comment: Please don't change the question, if you need to talk to the answerer please use the comment box otherwise this question is no use to anyone else.

Comment: Sorry I have tried to fix it but the comment formating looks bad to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format is wrong, and I don't see any selectors in your code, which should look something like this:

```
#yourID {
    background-image: url('../img/headernew.jpg');
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 900px) {
    #yourID {
        background-image: url('../img/headerold.jpg');
    }
}
```

It looks like you were trying to put the media queries inside the selector block, but instead the query must wrap the selectors and rules you want to use.

Comment: I have made the following changes but still am having problems as it dose not seem to work. I am using a 27in iMac and a iPad3 for testing. This is what my code now looks like.div.art-header-jpeg {
    background-image: url('../img/headernew.jpg');
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 900px) {
   div.art-header-jpeg {
        background-image: url('../img/headerold.jpg');
    }
}

Comment: You shouldn't put code in comments, because its difficult to read, but you can update your question :) Also, it isn't really relevant what computer you are using.